# Samsung S4 Screen Problem

Tags: samsung, broken-screen

I dropped my phone face down not to hard on the floor, the battery came out and when I put the battery back in, the screen was showing then turned into certain blocks of the screen showing then only to the top part of the screen showing. I have tried restarting, putting battery out then in. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the underlying hardware that makes the screen run is damaged. In a touchscreen, or all monitors in general, a complex series of wires sends electrical impulses to the individual led diodes (a set of Red, Green, Blue is called a pixel). If one of the main wires became damaged or loosened, it will seriously mess up the screen's viewing output.

Judging by the color difference in your photo, the only part receiving signals from the graphics unit is above a defined line (is that a crack? If so, that is most likely where a breaking event could have occurred).

Since it fell down hard enough to eject the battery, the internal components most likely suffered some damage. If you have a service provider, they might be able to look at your phone in more detail and tell you exactly where the issue is and how (if possible) to fix it.

Best of luck!